# Vue 2 v-for with multiple items

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

When trying to fill a table with rows using v-for it is quite easy to map the v-for elements 1:1 with the rows like:

```
<template>
  <table>
    <tr v-for="item in items"><td>{{item}}</td></tr>
  </table>
</template>
```

My question is: how can I create multiple rows (eg td elements) per item (see following pseudocode):

```
<template>
  <table>
    <nothing v-for="item in items">
      <tr><td>{{item.line1}}</td></tr>
      <tr><td>{{item.line2}}</td></tr>
    </nothing>
  </table>
</template>
```

Here `<nothing>` should not be emitted in the DOM as a level, only `<td>` directly under `<table>`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue.js, you can use tag `<template>`, it does exactly what you meant by `nothing`.

```
<table id="t1">
    <template v-for="item in items">
        <tr><td>{{item.line1}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{item.line2}}</td></tr>
    </template>
</table>
```

But alternatively, you can wrap these two lines into `tbody` tag to actually render it and group the lines in two, e.g., for styling.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dmitry's solution, typically, you would want to loop your rows, and use blocks in the same `td`.

```html
  <table>
      <tr v-for="item in items">
        <td>
          {{item.line1}} <br />
          {{item.line2}}
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

or

```html
  <table>
      <tr v-for="item in items">
        <td>
          <div>{{item.line1}}</div>
          <div>{{item.line2}}</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: This is no solution to the question but could be a solution otherwise. It was not easy to use this for my current problem due due different colspans per row